# Efficient Data Structure to represent matrix

Tags: java, data-structures, genetic-algorithm

I am currently working on a solution for exam timetable scheduling for a university. I was thinking of using Genetic Algorithms.

Right now I started with a simple example so that I catch on what is happening since I am new to all this. In this example I have 10 exams, 6 students and 6 available time-slots. I am representing a chromosome such that I have 10 positions in a bit-string with values varying from 1-6 representing time-slots so for example: `[3 1 4 1 3 5 5 6 4 2]` implies that exam 1 takes place in the 3rd time-slot, exam 2 in the 1st time-slot, etc...

Now if I have the following array representing which exams are each of the students taking:

```
int[][] students_exams = 
{
    {3, 1, 2, 5, 8},   // student 1
    {10, 4, 5, 7},     // student 2
    {1, 2, 3, 6},      // student 3
    {2, 7, 4, 5},      // student 4
    {1, 6, 2, 10},     // student 5
    {8, 9, 1, 3}       // student 6
};
```

how can I efficiently represent this information as a [n x n] matrix where n is the number of exams (in this case 10) where *M[i][j]* is equal to the *number of students taking exam i and exam j?*

Is there a data structure I can use or do I have to compare each exam with each other exam and have an incrementing counter? Because thinking about it, I think this will not be efficient for the amount of students and exams I will have in reality.

If you can refer me to any papers or references you'll be of much help to me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for space efficiency or processor efficiency?  You can't have both since processing for efficient space adds to processor overhead that isn't there if you aren't concerned with space efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the brute force approach you are probably trying to avoid:

```
class testMatrixSO{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[][] students_exams = 
        {
        {3, 1, 2, 5, 8},   // student 1
        {10, 4, 5, 7},     // student 2
        {1, 2, 3, 6},      // student 3
        {2, 7, 4, 5},      // student 4
        {1, 6, 2, 10},     // student 5
        {8, 9, 1, 3}       // student 6
        };

        int[][] finalMatrix = new int[10][10];
        //here is the part that creates your matrix
        for(int i=0; i<students_exams.length; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<students_exams[i].length; j++)
                for(int k=0; k<students_exams[i].length; k++)
                    if(j != k) finalMatrix[students_exams[i][j]-1][students_exams[i][k]-1]++;



        //print results
        for(int i=0; i < finalMatrix.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < finalMatrix[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(finalMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

on a positive note, if you assume each student will have 6 or less exams, then we can confidently say that the loop that updates the matrix will execute less than (number of students)*(6*6) times.  i.e. the algorith is of linear order, O(n).